# How to show descriptions when a user hovers over a form element

Tags: theming, javascript

How is the descriptions tooltip done in rubik theme by development seed? I have looked through the entire theme and couldn't identify which is handling this. Is it js or css?
https://github.com/developmentseed/rubik
[image: screenshot with tooltip]

Comment: What descriptions tooltip? I installed Rubik and see only browser default tooltips. Perhaps post an example image

Comment: added a screenshot with tooltip, showing some help about the name field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire tooltip code is found within the Rubik theme in the files core.css and core-rtl.css.  The majority is within core.css.  The specific piece that *shows* the tooltip is:

```
.page-content .form-item:hover > .description { display:block; }
```

But each tooltip has text contained in `<div class='description'></div>`, so you can search through core.css/core-rtl.css and find statements regarding `.description`